# Confused over Mac Pro 1.1 EFI firmware 32 vs 64 bit: patch firmware or OS installer?

Tags: mac-pro, efi, 32-bit

I have the original Intel Mac Pro 1.1 and I know it has a 64-bit CPU (Xeon), yet it has 32-bit firmware. However, I know that it's possible to patch it to run 64-bit OS, like OS X Mavericks (which I used to run on it via [SFOTT](https://oemden.com/sixty-four-on-thirty-two-sfott/)).

I now run VMware ESXi 6.0.0 on the machine so I can run VMs. ESXi 6.0 is the last version officially support on the Mac Pro 1.1, but just like OS X Lion -> Mtn Lion, I am reading that it *is* indeed possible to run VMware ESXi 6.5 on the machine.

My question is this: **Do I need to "patch" the firmware of the Mac Pro 1.1, or simply the ISO installer of the OS?** When I installed Mac OS X Mavericks I simply patched the ISO. I found [this post about installing ESXi 6.0 on a Mac Pro 1.1](https://neckercube.com/index.php/2016/04/11/bringing-an-old-mac-pro-back-to-life-with-esxi-6-0/) and in the comments the author says he *thinks* the process is the same for ESXi 6.5, but is not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. I was able to simply patch the ISO/installer: https://hacker223.wordpress.com/tag/macpro/